# How to merge 2 series in pandas where nulls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In a Dataframe/table I have data something like this

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name1 | name2  |
+----+-------+--------+
|  0 | John  |        |
|  1 |       | Nathan |
|  2 | Andy  |        |
+----+-------+--------+
```

I want to merge them to an another column where nulls or empties gets filled either of the name column something like this

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| id | name1 | name2  | merged_names |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
|  0 | John  |        | John         |
|  1 |       | Nathan | Nathan       |
|  2 | Andy  |        | Andy         |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

How can I do this in pandas Dataframe

Comment: `df['merged_names'] = df[['name1','name2']].fillna('').sum(1)` might help

Comment: that works, it would be great if you describe it on answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the empty cells are actually empty strings, you can do so:

```
df['merged_names'] = df1['name1'] + df2['name2']
```

If the empty cells are `np.nan`, you can use `replace` in this way:

```
df['merged_names'] = df1['name1'].replace(np.nan, '') + df2['name2'].replace(np.nan, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'name1': ['John', np.nan, 'Andy'],
                   'name2': [np.nan, 'Nathan', np.nan]})

df['merged'] = df['name1'].combine_first(df['name2'])

print(df)

   id name1   name2  merged
0   0  John     NaN    John
1   1   NaN  Nathan  Nathan
2   2  Andy     NaN    Andy
```

If your values are empty strings instead of `NaN`, you can convert to `NaN` first via:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```